# How to know a hostname is a computer "Server" or just personal "Desktop"

Tags: php, linux, ip, hosting, detect

This is a list of hostname, I got from my clients.

```
----------------------
msnbot-207-46-194-96.search.msn.com. <-- Server
cpe-98-151-173-209.socal.res.rr.com. <-- Desktop
msnbot-157-55-33-20.search.msn.com.  <-- Server
static.178.114.63.178.clients.your-server.de. <-- Server
----------------------
```

I get those information by using command `"host IP_Address"` on linux. 
Is there anyway to know that hostname or IP Address is coming from Personal Desktop or Servers? Any kind of command Linux, PHP, Perl, BashCode is fine.

Thank you,

Comment: @sachleen: Repeating the question is not a comment ;)

Comment: What happens if a server and a desktop reside behind NAT and the hostname is something like `core1-gbit-sw.mit.edu`? Shouldn't there be two more categories, *Servetop* and *Deskver*?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm asking OP what he thinks the difference is. If you can make a distinction, then you can write a program to follow those parameters. If you can't do the former, you can't do the latter.

Comment: @sachleen: Well, you can just read the question, which asks "what is the difference". From that I'm fairly sure we can gather that the OP doesn't know the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It doesn't ask "what is the difference". It asks how we can classify them according to the difference he doesn't know.

Comment: LOL. The example "Desktop" was my IP, others 2 is from "MSN" and the last one is "your-server.de" . Teeheee. That how I had this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably there is a fundamental difference between a server and a desktop that you decline to offer. As such, I would conclude that a server hosts a web site. Therefore, one might port scan the host names and check to see if port 80 (or suitable alternative) is open.

Comment: That's an _incredibly_ narrow definition of "server".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And... the one he offers is better?

Comment: No. But if I were to offer you a rotten apple, would you eat it just because you had a _more_ rotten apple as an alternative?

Comment: I like the one check port 80 open. I think If it opened then 99% it is a Server Machine.

Comment: @KenLe The issue is that port 80 being closed does not mean it is not a server.

Answer (score 3):

Well, no. Because *there is no practical distinction*, other than a convention between men and women that a desktop sits on an actual desk floor whereas a server tends to sit in a rack.

Certainly, from a hostname, you have zero chance of discovering programatically whether Neville or Ginger would describe the machine as a server or a porn machine.